SwiftUI ActivityKit error `unsupportedTarget` when following Flo's YouTube tutorial
At the moment I'm following Flo's YouTube video on activity kit and how to use it to create live activities on the lock screen (I will explore creating dynamic island feature later but for now, I just want a live activity).
I have created the activity as follows:

The code:
Widget file containing the widget
This is inside a separate widget target.

import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI
import ActivityKit


struct TimerView : View {
    let context: ActivityViewContext<LiveActivityTimerAttributes>

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(context.attributes.timerName)
                .font(.headline)
            
            Text(context.state.endTime, style: .timer)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}

struct OfflineWidget: Widget {
    let kind: String = "OfflineWidget"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        ActivityConfiguration(for: LiveActivityTimerAttributes.self) { context in
            
            TimerView(context: context)
            
            
        } dynamicIsland: { context in
            DynamicIsland {
                // Expanded
                DynamicIslandExpandedRegion(.bottom) {
                    Text("Dynamic island isn't supported yet")
                }
            } compactLeading: {
                Text("Dynamic island isn't supported yet")
            } compactTrailing: {
                Text("Dynamic island isn't supported yet")
            } minimal: {
                Text("Dynamic island isn't supported yet")
            }

        }

    }
}

In my main view (Inside the main swiftUI target), I have:
@State private var activity: Activity<LiveActivityTimerAttributes>?

...
Button("Start live activity") {
                    // Create attributes
                    let attributes = LiveActivityTimerAttributes(timerName: "Dummy timer")
                    
                    // Create initial state
                    let state = LiveActivityTimerAttributes.ContentState(endTime: Date().addingTimeInterval(60))
                    
                    let content = ActivityContent(state: state, staleDate: nil)
                    
                    // Request to start activity
                    do {
                        activity = try Activity<LiveActivityTimerAttributes>.request(
                            attributes: attributes,
                            content: content,
                            pushType: nil // NEED to pass nil here. Defaut is to allow push notifications to update the live activity
                        )
                    } catch {
                        print("Error requesting live activity: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                
                Button("Stop live activity") {
                    // Update activity state
                    let state = LiveActivityTimerAttributes.ContentState(endTime: .now)
                    
                    // Request activity to end
                    let content = ActivityContent(state: state, staleDate: nil)
                    
                    Task {
                        await activity?.end(content, dismissalPolicy: .immediate)
                    }
                }


The problem:
However when I run the app in an iOS 18.1 simulator I get the ActivityKit.ActivityAuthorizationError.unsupportedTarget error output to me, and of course no live activity, not even a dead one. I also get this when running on a real device.
According to Apple's documentation, the unsupportedTarget error occurs when...

the app doesn’t have the required entitlement to start a Live Activities.


The question:
What entitlements is it speaking about here?
a. Is it speaking about a special Live Activities target, well in my Xcode I see nothing of the kind:

b. Is it because I am on an Apple free developer account? In which case, why would this be limiting me as I make sure to set the pushType: nil when I request a live activity.
I'd really appreciate a little help, thanks!

Have you added the NSSupportsLiveActivities key? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/displaying-live-data-with-live-activities#Add-support-for-Live-Activities-to-your-app

Yes, I did that.

I found out the answer;
It's because my Supports Live Activities key was in the widget's Info.plist instead of my main target!
